# How can I limit a method to be called by .Net Core projects?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a `Common` Project that is called by the other projects (`.Net Framework`);

I've now created a new project that is `.Net Core`, but this project can't call a specific constructor from the `Common` as it uses a `.Net Framework` feature.

I want to limit the `.Net Core` project so it's not possible to call the `.Net Framework` method as it causes a `FileNotFoundException` and can be confusing for the devs.

This is the Common class I've mentioned

```
namespace Common
{
    public class Example
    {
        public Example()
        {
            // here's the .Net Framework bit
        }

        public Example(string variable)
        {
            // everyone can call this constructor
        }
    }
}
```

is this actually possible?

I've tried using `#if NETCOREAPP` but the `Common` project is actually `.Net Framework`, the caller is the `.Net Core` so it doesn't work

Thanks!

Comment: Do the two constructors _have_ to be in the exact same class?

Comment: Can you multi-target your Common project at both .NET Framework and .NET Standard? So you get one DLL built for each? It's easy to do with `<TargetFrameworks>net472;netstandard21</TargetFrameworks>` or similar. Then you can use e.g. `#if` to produce slightly different code for each target. Referencing a .NET Framework projects from a .NET Core one is a bad idea, anyway: it works through large amounts of magic.

Answer (score 1):

You should not go that route. The idea coming from Microsoft is to use .Net Standard to produce libraries which can be consumed by both .NET Core and .Net Framework.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer my question. I know it's not the ideal scenario, but this is an already existent project and widely used by the others.